# AngularJS Controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Recently faced angularjs controller behaviour. Someone accidently from team did structured DOM like this : -

```
<div ng-controller="firstController">
 <div ng-controller="secondController">
</div>
</div>


// This should have been structured like :- 

<div ng-controller="firstController"></div>
<div ng-controller="secondController"></div>
```

Below are my observations that I need to ask whether this is really a consequence of this ?

1. broadcast events are fired twice. ( Not using rootscope for sending/recieving events)
2. I was under impression that I can access models of secondController from firstController; which is not happening.
3. I am really skeptical when secondController accesses '$scope' is it local or parent ? ( I assume both)

Please correct my understanding. Really appreciate if anyone has solution to deal issue ( perticular 1st one)

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your controllers. Also, which version of angular are you using?

Comment: controller code will help. Also in first case, class is used instead of ng-controller

Comment: My bad.. I did mistake .. but I will put some code.

Answer (score 0):

While modifying the code as you mentioned, you will not be able to trigger the models of secondController from firstController. Because currently there is no parent child relation between these two controller.

In this case the `$scope` in the second controller will be definitely local. You cannot access the `$scope` variable of first controller from this. If you need to communicate between these two controllers you need to user Services to transfer data between services.